# Delphi Mobile App Send Image Through Tidtcpclient (Connection Closed Gracefully)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am using Delphi 10.2 and build a mobile app 
one of my tasks to send images from mobile to a server 
I get a code from stackoverflow to do this and run it but it is not working

**server side code on execute**

```
type
  TSendRec = record
    SONo: string;
    Text: string;
    Bitmap: TBitmap;
  end;


procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  MIRec: TSendRec;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  try
  MIRec.SONo := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
  MIRec.Text := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
  MIRec.Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;

    ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(ms, -1, False);
      ms.Position := 0;
      MIRec.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(ms);
    finally
      ms.Free;
    end;
    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(MIRec.SONo);
        Memo1.Lines.Add(MIRec.Text);
        MIRec.Bitmap.SaveToFile('C:\To Receive\test.bmp');
      end
      );
  finally
    MIRec.Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**and Client code is**

```
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MIRec: TSendRec;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  MIRec.SONo := IntToStr(Ticket_ID);
  MIRec.Text := 'Pic_'+IntToStr(Ticket_ID);
  MIRec.Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  MIRec.Bitmap.Assign(imgPhotoLibraryImage.Bitmap);
  try
    IdTCPClient1.Connect;
    try
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn(MIRec.SONo);
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn(MIRec.Text);
      ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        MIRec.Bitmap.SaveToStream(ms);
        IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
        IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(ms, 0, True);
        ShowMessage('Image Uploaded');
        imgPhotoLibraryImage.Bitmap.Assign(nil);
      finally
        ms.Free;
      end;
    finally
      IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
    end;
  finally
    MIRec.Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

now in the server side I get an error **Connection closed gracefully**

any help plz

Comment: thanks for your replay but do you have any sample for sending record data type like this type
  TSendRec = record
    SONo: string;
    Text: string;
    Bitmap: TBitmap;
  end; through TIdHTTP / TIdHTTPServer

Comment: FWIW, an exception is not necessarily an error. They're most commonly used for handling errors, but exceptions are not errors. There are good exceptions too, such as this one. The only time you'll ever see it is when you're running your application in debug mode.

Answer (score 3):

### This is normal behavior.

`TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component. When a client connects, it runs in its own worker thread. The `TIdTCPServer.OnExecute` event is fired in the context of that thread in a continuous loop for the lifetime of the socket connection.

After the client sends the image stream, it disconnects from the server.

After the server reads the image stream, it exits the `OnExecute` event handler. The handler will be fired again, calling `ReadLn()`, which will detect the disconnect and raise the `EIdConnClosedGracefully` exception.

This is normal behavior. Just let the exception escape the event handler.  Don't catch it (or, if you do, be sure to re-raise it). `TIdTCPServer` will handle the exception for you, closing the client socket and stopping the thread that manages the socket.

---

FYI, on a side note, the default image format of FMX's `TBitmap.SaveTo...()` methods is PNG, not BMP.

Comment: Dear Remy, thx for your help, can you please clarify your comment "Just let the server handle the exception so it can close the socket and stop the thread that manages the socket" and tell me more details what can I add in the code to solve this

Comment: @aoemam there is nothing to add, because there is nothing to solve. The code is acting correctly. Indy raises an exception if a read/write operation is performed after the socket connection has been closed. Just let it happen, don't catch the exception (or re-raise it if you do) and `TIdTCPServer` will handle it internally for you.

Comment: now my problem is that the server side application stopped at AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(ms, -1, False); and the memo not filled with the data sent from mobile and also the image not received also I want to tell you that I am tried to ignore sending the image and only send strings also the same error and no new action

Comment: The code is fine as shown. The writes and reads are balanced correctly. There is no reason for the code to block unless the data is not being transmitted over the network correctly. Use a network sniffer to verify.

Comment: Hi Remy, more thanks , i appreciate your effort , finally worked by putting LoadFromStream(ms); under finally of try

Comment: That is not a good place for it, because if `ReadStream()` fails, the stream data will be incomplete, so the load will also fail.  There is nothing wrong with the original code you showed.  Except for maybe the fact that FMX's `TBitmap` was not thread-safe until recently, so you might have to synchronize access to the `TBitmap` to the main UI thread.